# Jinja2 for Flask not picking up child templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to write an email html file with three parts: header, body and footer. These are wrapped inside a primary mail.html file which looks like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <p>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 12.727272033691406px; line-height: 1.2em; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border-spacing: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(231, 232, 232); border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px;" width="100%">

                    {% block head %}
                    {% endblock %}

                    {% block body %}
                    {% endblock %}
                <br/>

                     {% block footer %}
                     {% endblock %}
                </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
    </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Essentially one parent template with three child temnplates, all in the same directory. Child templates have been described between the following two tags:

```
{% extends "mail.html" %}
{% block head %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

When I run the following command:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

env = Environment(loader = PackageLoader('mailwrapper','mail_templates'))


template = env.get_template('mail.html')
template.render()
```

I only get the output with the html of `mail.html` but the child blocks are ignored and only empty lines are printed out instead. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that the full code? Your `email_header` block isn't defined in mail.html.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be 'head' instead of 'email_header'. Updated it. 'head' block has been defined inside a file called email_header.html which lives in the same directory as mail.html

Comment: You should either 1) include the 3 files in mail.html instead of using blocks, or 2) define all 3 blocks in a single file that extends mail.html and load that template

Comment: @VarunJain If you find the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get content into *head*, *body* or *footer* blocks, you should render either *head.html* template or *body.html* or *footer.html*. When you execute *head.html* template, it takes *mail.html* template and replaces the blocks with content. On the other hand, when you render *mail.html* template, the template doesn't know about *head.html* (or other) template that should replace the blocks with content.

Consider following example.

**mail.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

**head.html:**

```
{% extends "mail.html" %}
{% block head %}
Hello Email Head
{% endblock %}
```

**mailwrapper.py:**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader = PackageLoader('mailwrapper','mail_templates'))

template = env.get_template('head.html')
print(template.render())

>>> <html>
>>>   <body>
>>>     Hello Email Head
>>>   </body>
>>> </html>

template = env.get_template('mail.html')
print(template.render())

>>> <html>
>>>   <body>
>>>     
>>>   </body>
>>> </html>
```

I would recommend to have 1 main **mail.html** template with 3 blocks and bunch of other templates that extend the **mail.html** template, replacing content in all 3 blocks. For example

**friendly_mail.html:**

```
{% extends "mail.html" %}
{% block head %}
  Dear ...,
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  You have a good day.
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
  Sincerely,
    ...
{% endblock %}
```